# С++ как добавить элемент кратный к в массив перед i-ым элементом?

Tags: c++, массивы

Дан массив A размера N. Вставить 0 перед каждым элементом, индекс которого кратен K. Я написал функцию ZeroIn(a,col,k), которой передаются три параметра - искомый массив - a, число индексов, кратное k - col, и само к. Вопрос, как теперь добавить перед каждый индексом, кратным к 0? Используя только сдвиг.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ZeroIn(int *, int, int);
int N;
void main()
{
    int *a;
    int k;
    cin >> N;
    cin >> k;
    int col = 0;
    a = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
        if (i % k == 0)col++;
    }
    ZeroIn(a, col, k);
}

void ZeroIn(int *a, int col, int k)
{
    int *b;
    b = new int[N + col];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
        b[i] = a[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Что будет с последними элементами массива, когда в массив будут вставляться нули? И, второй вопрос, индекс 0 считать кратным k или нет?

Comment: И если вы перераспределяете массив, то, фактически, вам надо будет копировать элементы из старого массива в новый. Сдвиг элементов здесь совершенно излишний.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, 0 кратен k, последний элемент должен остаться. Для этого я и создал второй массив с размерностью большей на то количество элементов, сколько есть в массиве а кратных к

Comment: Формулировка "Вставить 0 перед каждым элементом, индекс которого кратен K." противоречит "перед каждый индексом, кратным к". Массив 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9. K=3. **Первая формулировка**. Элементы, индексы которых кратны K - 0, 3,6,9. Результатом должен быть 0 0 1 2 0 3 4 5 0 6 7 8 0 9. **Вторая формулировка**. Вставка перед индексами, кратными K, означает 0 в позициях K*i-1: 0 1 0 2 3 0 4 5 0 6 7 0 8 9

Answer (score 1):

У меня ощущение, что под сдвигом в вашей задаче понимается нечто иное, не `<<` или `>>`, а скорее `memmove` - сдвиг в памяти.

Тогда что-то типа

```
void ZeroIn(int * src, int * dest, int size, int K)
{
    *dest++ = 0;
    for(;; )
    {
        int cnt = (size < K) ? size : K;
        memmove(dest,src,cnt*sizeof(src[0]));
        dest += cnt;
        src  += cnt;
        size -= cnt;
        if (size > 0)
            *dest++ = 0;
        else break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int src[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int dest[15] = {0};
    ZeroIn(src,dest,10,3);
    for(auto x: src) cout << x << " ";
    cout << endl;
    for(int x: dest) cout << x << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Но, если откровенно, то мне кажется, что ваше задание хитрее, и преподаватель хочет, чтобы вы растолкали элементы в пределах одного массива - тогда и сдвиги, и отсутствие динамической памяти становится понятным.

Может, нужно именно это? Раздвинуть элементы массива (с потерей последних)?

Comment: вряд ли, здесь именно нужна два массива использовать, в один исходные значения, в другой уже с нулями

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void ZeroIn(int *, int, int);
int N;
int c = 0;
void main()
{
    int *a;
    int k;
    cin >> N;
    cin >> k;
    int col = 0;
    a = new int[N * N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
        if (i % k == 0)col++;
    }
    ZeroIn(a, col, k);
}

void ZeroIn(int *a, int col, int k)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)cout << a[y] << " ";
    for (int i = 0; i < N + col; i++)
    {
        if (i % k == 0)
        {
            for (int j = N + col; j >= c; j--) 
            {
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
            }
            a[c]= 0;
            c += 1;
        }
        c++;
    }

    cout << endl ;

    for (int i = 0; i < N + col; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    delete[] a;

    system("pause");
}
```